# Can i improve gaming experience on my laptop by adding an external GPU or graphics card?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, performance, gpu, gaming

I have an
Acer Aspire E5- 575G Signature Edition
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200 
CPU @ 2.50GHz  2.70GHz
RAM: 8.00GB
With a NVIDIA GeForce 940MX

I've been getting notifications, that my system doesn't meet the minimum requirements for optimal settings on a few games. I wanted to know if I can add an external GPU/eGPU (or whatever is needed) to solve this/increase my laptop's performance for a better gaming experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to know if I can add an external GPU/eGPU (or whatever is needed) to solve this/increase my laptop's performance for a better gaming experience.

No.  An external GPU is only possible with USB 3.1 Gen 2 and/or Thunderbolt 3.  Your laptop has neither.  *Whatever, you find that supports anything else other than that, will be worse than your 940MX.*

Even if your laptop had the required ports, you would require a power supply, unless you purchased an enclosure designed for the purpose you describe.  Those external GPU enclosures are extremely expensive and don't even include the GPU.

There are perhaps ways to hack together a solution.  It would still cost a good amount of money, and you would still have a major performance bottleneck, your processor.

> a single USB Type-C 3.1 port that accommodates up to 5 Gbps

The port described in the above description is for a USB 3.1 Gen 1 port.

[Source](https://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/acer-aspire-e-15-e5-575g-57d4)

USB 3.1 Gen 1 and USB 3.1 Gen 2 is described as the following:

> - USB 3.0 is now called USB 3.1 Gen 1 (Speed up to 5Gbps)
> - USB 3.1 is now called USB 3.1 Gen 2 (Speed up to 10Gbps)

[Source](https://www.msi.com/blog/usb-3-1-gen1-gen2-explained)

Thunderbolt 3 is described as the following:

> Thunderbolt v3: 4× PCI Express 3.0, DisplayPort 1.2 (2 streams), USB 3.1 gen. 2

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface))

Comment: So basically, my 940MX is one of the best i can have with this computer without spending a major amount of money and messing with my computer. Is that right? The list you gave me there, is that what i would have to get to add external stuff? Do you suggest staying with what I have, even if I, hypothetically, have the money to invest in the extensions needed to "upgrade" my laptop? Thanks!

Comment: What list?  I explained what is required for an external GPU.  Your hardware cannot be upgraded.  It is not possible to connect an external GPU to your device.  That would require Thunderbolt 3.  You won’t be able to hack together a solution due to lack of connection providing enough bandwidth to support it.